# What merit to fight in the dark?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

I've only found Forces spells, such as Nightsight (Forces •), to see better in the dark. When a mage doesn't have Forces Arcanum, is there a Merit she could learn to fight better in the dark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book of the Dead, a Geist: the Sin Eaters sourcebook, has a movement style merit called Spelunker that can accomplish this. The second rung of the style, Cave Sense, allows you to ignore darkness penalties out of combat and halve them in combat.

Comment: *Book of the Dead* is great for Sin-Eaters but is technically a general *WoD* supplement and not specific to *Geist*. Also Cave Sense requires "some source of light" to work.
>If the character operates with some source of light underground,she can ignore all penalties due to darkness if she has a moment to gather her senses. In combat, she doesn’t have that time but she’s still at an advantage. Halve any penalties for acting in darkness. (*WoD:BotD* p. 92)